# solr schema design for 100 over tables

Tags: solr

I am designing the schema for my solr server. I have 2 oracle databases and 100 over tables to index for these two tables.

How should I go about indexing these tables:

1. 1 schema with multiple entity - each entity maps to 1 table
2. 1 solr core for each database/table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be thinking about this that way at all.

Instead, you should think about what you will want to **find**, prototype that with a small data set and then figure out how to map your database to the search index.

You may end up indexing a very small part of the database and getting back from Solr only relevant IDs which you then use to lookup your complex structures for the actual content.

Comment: can you elaborate further?

Comment: what if I have multiple datasets?

Comment: The main point that you need to think backwards from search. E.g. If you get 10 results per page - what is the "result item". That's (usually) the granularity of your search document and the tables get manipulated to match on the way into Solr. If you have multiple searched datasets, you need to decided if you can search more than one at once or not. If they are always separate - use separate collections. If they are together, combine them and split them with a flag of sorts.

Comment: If I am using solr for multiple applications databases? Should I be using 1 index for each application and 1 entity for each database table?

Comment: It is the same question. Are you searching across multiple applications' data together? If yes - collocate. If no, do not.

Comment: are you able to give an example of the schema.xml with 2 tables? I cant really figure out how to index 2 tables or  more.

Comment: If you are using one schema file, than it is just an overlap superset of all possible fields that can come from either of your tables. All non-common fields would have to be non-compulsory. You may need to create additional fields to differentiate record types. The shipped examples show that to some degree by allowing to index quite different xml files in the docs directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might use multiple cores to manage multiple entities that are different enough to justify having different indexes for each.